# How do i not display element with price over ??? from container

Tags: javascript, function, containers

i would like the function to hide every element with the price over 150. i made script that makes an item in shop from a container. now i want to make Price categories so onclick it only shows items under 150 for example.

```
  var ItemCollection =

[
    {

        Name: 'IVY PA',
        Price: 160,
        Picture: 'some pic'
    },
    {

        Name: 'IVY P',
        Price: 100,
        Picture: 'some pic'
    }, 

  ];

 ItemCollection.forEach(generateItem);
$('#Collection').append(content);


 var content = "";






 function generateItem(item, index, arrays) {


content = content + '\n' +
    '        <li class="Shoe"><a href="#' + item.Name + '\'">\n' +
    '            <div>\n' +
    '                <img class="ItemPicture"\n' +
    '                     src=" ' + item.Picture + '">\n' +
    '\n' +
    '            </div>\n' +
    '            <div class="ItemInfo">\n' +
    '                <p>' + item.Name + '</p>\n' +
    '                <p>' + item.Price + '$</p>\n' +
    '            </div>\n' +
    '            </a>\n' +
    '        </li>\n';


 }


 function under150() {
   var price = "";




var Shoe = document.getElementsByClassName("Shoe");


  price = ItemCollection.item.Price;
 console.log(ItemCollection.item.Price);


if (price > 150){

    Shoe.style.display = "none";

}
else {}

 }
```

there is my current try but i know it's completely wrong i need a little help, so if u have any ideas i'll be very thankful.

Comment: Please review [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to improve your question accordingly. Especially (a) some attention to spelling, (b) some better code formatting, (c) turning your code into a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do), if possible, and (d) some clarification of what the issue with your current code is. Cheers!

Comment: Let's just start with, why are your "prices" strings instead of numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate on each item and then check the price, if price is more than 150 then hide that particular item.

```
function under150() {
    var Shoe = document.getElementsByClassName("Shoe");
    for(var i=0;i<Shoe.length;i++)
    {
        price = ItemCollection[i].Price;
        if (price > 150){
            Shoe[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this work but it doesn't display them even before clicking the button with the function any idea what mistake i could've done?

Comment: Maybe because you are not appending content in your html

Comment: well yeah it worked, sorry altough as i said it doesn't display those items before clicking the button with the function. If i remove this answer the items are there but when i add they disapear as they should  but beofre using the function

Comment: Are you calling this "under150" function from anywhere else?

Comment: found the mistake as i was messing with the code accidently deleted () from the onclick in html so it looked like onclick="under150" then i added () and it workes. Thank you very mush for your help. it fully works as intended.